# Office UI Dialog not showing correctly on SPFX Web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, react, office-ui-fabric-react

On the SharePoint Workspace the UI dialog works fine. The dialog comes out when you click on Forward Case.

[image]

When I have gulp packaged the solution and adding the app (locally on gulp) then I get this when I click on Forward Case.

[image]

So the dialog needs to pop out much further and onto the main screen and not just within the web part.

Is this anything that can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did simple test in my online environment while can't reproduce.

I think this related to CSS, you'd better use developer tool to debug/compare the CSS difference.

[image]